# How early can I apply for a Swiss long-term visa?

Tags: visa, schengen, switzerland

Hi there I will be heading to Switzerland for an exchange program. The embassy & the school recommends that the process be applied asap as processing takes 2 - 3 months (or more if more proof etc. is needed).

The semester starts officially in end-Feb so is now too early to apply ? As in would the embassy accept the application since for Schengen tourist visas (type C) you can only do so earliest 3 months before.

Comment: It's true that consulates do not have to accept application for Schengen short-stay visas more than three months in advance but they typically have no such rules for long-stay visa application, as they are regulated by an entirely different set of rules and can take longer to process. I can't comment for Switzerland in particular but I would approach the consulate already.

Comment: @Gala thanks for the information. Yeah I guess I will approach them. From what I know the applications are sent back to Switzerlad for processing so best be safe and do so early. Thanks again for your help!